# Get content on change with java

Tags: java

How to get the content of a web page with java if it changes.

For example the first start of the program in java shows the default content, but if the site have some options for example with [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax), or [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) that are changing the content somehow,

I want to get the content if it was changed, but with only one start of the program.

Only one compiling;

1. Get content
2. If content change somehow - output it again in the console and this time
   output will show the whole content but updated

Comment: There's not enough information here to determine what is being asked.  Can you edit your post and restate the question?

Comment: Let's say that i'm changing the content after i run my console application, then i want to detect somehow if the content is changet and if it is, then output something in console

Answer (score 0):

There are only two possibilities:

1. The web site tells your java program when something changes.  This requires that you design and implement a protocol by which this happens; or
2. Your java code fetches the web content on a regular basis (i.e. once a minute) and compares the retrieved data to the previous copy (allowing for potentially "normal" changes like timestamps).

There's no automatic-change-detection magic available,  you have to build your own based on your specific situation, which only you know.